# IOS Archive is stopping while Alamofire Object Mapper building. (Xcode 11)

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, alamofireobjectmapper

I am trying to archive my project, but it stop in every point. It doesn't give me any error. It just not keep going. It always stop when AlamofireObjectMapper is building.

Do you know any idea about this situation?